# How do I remove quotation marks from imported csv file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv

I wrote the following code to copy the contents of a CSV file to a datatable, however the contents contains quotation marks. I have tried several methods to remove them, but am stuck now as to how to do it. If anyone could show me the way I would be very grateful.

```
        Dim line As String
        Dim strArray() As String
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim row As DataRow

        Using strm As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("" & Spreadsheet & "")

            line = strm.ReadLine
            strArray = Split(line, ",")
            For Each s As String In strArray
                dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(s))
            Next

            While Not strm.Peek = -1
                line = strm.ReadLine
                row = dt.NewRow()
                Dim mySplit() As String = line.Split(",")

                For i As Integer = 0 To mySplit.Length - 1
                    row(i) = mySplit(i)
                Next
                dt.Rows.Add(row)
            End While
        End Using
```

Comment: Take a look at [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) - it has an option to handle quoted fields.  In addition, it is very useful for parsing CSV (and other delimited files) in general.

Comment: This is not how you parse CSV files ... naïve splitting on commas without regard for quoted fields is a recipe for disaster

Comment: There are several projects available for processing CSV files, such as Linq2CSV http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library. You are better off using one of these. Quotes have a purpose in a CSV file. Simply stripping them off is not a sufficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some good comments were left about other approaches to this, if you **must** stick with this approach you could replace all quotations with empty strings using the Replace function:

```
row(i) = Replace(mySplit(i), Chr(34), String.Empty)
```

If there are quotations you want to keep and are only worried about the first and last characters I recommend checking out the Mid or SubString functions.

Comment: Might as well just remove on the line variable for less calls.

Comment: @Blam I agree.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

There are extension functions for manipulating strings.

```
row(i) = mySplit(i).Replace("""", "")
```